# Mysql & Node - Erro: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, node.js, servidor

Quando tento fazer o login no meu site, aparece-me o erro: ER_NOT_SUPPORTED_AUTH_MODE
Pelo que estive a ver acho que tem a haver com a ligação à base de dados, que não está correta.

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: "127.0.0.1",
    user: "aafachada",
    password: "password",
    database: "revistas",
    charset: "utf8",
    multipleStatements: true
});
```

Eu já tive o user e a password como root, mas não funcionou, e já meti de password a que defini como a pass do MySql Server, mas também não funcionou.

Não sei o que é suposto meter nesses campos para que funcionem.

Já tentei recorrer ao método de criar um usuário através do MySql Workbench, mas não sei se o fiz bem ou não, mas não deu para entrar com esse user e pass.

Lembro-me que na altura em que instalei os vários programas do MySql, apareceu-me uma secção de Users, mas passei-a à frente porque achava que não precissava.

Agora como não a consigo encontrar não sei se é aquilo que preciso para poder fazer a ligação.

Se me puderem ajudar agradecia bastante, até agora não consegui solucionar com as respostas a perguntas semelhantes à minha.

Comment: precisas confirmar como está a configuração de autenticação no `mysql`. Tenta usar isso como parâmetro adicional ao criar a conexão: `insecureAuth : true` e veja se já resolve

Comment: Já consegui!! Tinha o User e a Pass mal, mas depois de mudar e utilizar esse parâmetro já deu! Muito Obrigada!!